# function main without definition in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Why this code compile successful in C and will give you an error in C++?

```
int main;
```

Is it standard-conforming in a hosted environment? Can you quote the standard?

I've tested it with gcc.

Comment: @SparKot c++ is NOT strongly typed. It has *weak static* type discipline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why this code compile successful in C and will give you an error in C++?

Because of C++ name mangling. Basically, in all practical implementations, the linker looks for a **symbol** named `main` (or variants of it, I've seen `_main` on Apple's platforms) - in C, that can be either the `main()` function *or an extern storage variable named* `main` - the point is that usually C implementations (compilers, toolchains) don't differentiate between variables and functions at the linker level, that's why providing one symbol, be it either a variable or a function, named `main()` **may seem to be enough**. In fact, in a hosted environment, as per the Standard, the resulting program (executable) won't be conforming, because there, it is required that the `main()` **function** be implemented.

In C++, usually name mangling is used (in order to achieve features of C++ such as function overloading), and that means that the compiler names the resulting symbol in the executable file differently depending on its type, on the fact if it's a function, a variable, *a function with a different signature*, and other circumstances. So the linker basically won't find the symbol corresponding to the expected `int main(int, char *[])` function and will issue an error message.

> Is it standard-conforming?

Not defining the `main()` function isn't (see the first part). As far as I can tell, having a variable named `main` along with the main function is valid C++, but it is *certainly bad practice.*

> Can you quote the Standard?

Yes please (emphasis mine):

> C++ 98, paragraph 3.6.1:
>
> A program **shall contain** a global function called `main()`, which is the designated start of the program. It is *implementation-defined* whether a program in a *freestanding environment* is required to define a `main()` function.
>
> C99, paragraph 5.1.2.2.1
>
> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
> prototype for this function. I

Comment: It looks like not defining main is not necessarily wrong, though probably very unusual. `It
is implementation-deﬁned whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to deﬁne a main
function.` (via 3.6.1.1)

Comment: @H2CO3 : Explained well.. but last line could yo please elaborate for me anyway +1

Comment: @TomKerr, I take it the OP isn't testing this thing out in a freestanding environment.

Comment: @TomKerr Very good point! However, I would consider that a separate case. Freestanding environments are tricky (even after reading the relevant parts of the Standard), and I'm sure OP uses a let-us-call-it-"normal" environment :)

Comment: @Omkant Thanks! So basically, the Standard (almost-always) requires that the `main()` function be defined by the writer of the program.

Comment: Yes, we're talking about hosted environment

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov I added that to your question. And this is a really good question, +1.

Comment: So, this code should not compile in both standard-conforming C and C++ compilers, except freestanding environment?

Comment: @chris I won't disagree. It's just language lawyer talk.  Answers are relevant to any one on google, so clarity doesn't hurt.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov This code should not compile in a conforming and hosted C++ environment and **may** compile in a conforming C environment, however, the **resulting program would not be conforming.**

Comment: So, it's ok by the standard that in C this code can compile and run, right? And why "may compile" and not just "must compile"? "in C, that can be either the main() function or an extern storage variable named main".

Comment: @H2CO3, I suggested "hosting" as an alternative to your word choice of "normal".

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov That doesn't depend on the Standard, that depends on the implementation. If a program doesn't implement `main()` as a function, it's not conformant, therefore the Standard doesn't impose any requirements for it, so it essentially invokes UB, so it doesn't have to run. It may, however, compile based on paractical and common implementation details, but that's the same I just explained in the answer.

Comment: @chris that's called a "hosted" environment, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

From [ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E)](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pd) (aka C++98), *3.6.1 Main function*:

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This
>   function shall not be overloaded. It shall 2   have a return type of
>   type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All
>   implementations   shall allow both of the following definitions of
>   main:
>           `int main() { /* ... */ }`   and
>                      `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }`   In the latter form argc shall be the number of arguments passed to the
>   program from the environment in   which the program is run. If argc is
>   nonzero these arguments shall be supplied in argv[0] through
>   argv[argc-1] as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated
>   multibyte strings (NTMBSs)   (17.3.2.1.3.2) and argv[0] shall be the
>   pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the   name
>   used to invoke the program or "". The value of argc shall be
>   nonnegative. The value of   argv[argc] shall be 0. [Note: it is
>   recommended that any further (optional) parameters be added after
>   argv. ]

---

> The function main shall not be used (3.2) within a program. The
>   linkage (3.5) of main is 3   implementation-defined. A program that
>   declares main to be inline or static is ill-formed. The   name main is
>   not otherwise reserved. [Example: member functions, classes, and
>   enumerations can be   called main, as can entities in other
>   namespaces. ]

---

`int main;` does not comply with the above ("All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main", "The function main shall not be used (3.2) within a program").

Comment: And what? I don't know that you mean. And yes, i saw this quote before

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov You may want to have a look at my answer. Also, to Brian: merely quoting the Standard without **any** explanation is not very constructive.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is clearer.  I have added some explanation.

Comment: @H2CO3: Given that it's hard for non-experts to even *find* the relevant portions of the standards (and sometimes even the standard text itself), I think quoting the standard, especially if proper citations are used, is at least an above-average-quality answer.

Comment: @R.. Be patient! I'm going to quote the Standard also. I was just searching for the right quote. Also, a quote without explanation might not be the best solution, exactly for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not complaining about your answer, just saying (perhaps this belongs on meta, but oh well) that I think a properly-cited quotation from the relevant standards is at least an above-average/good-quality answer on Stack Overflow. Of course commentary/explanation can make it even better, and well-explained answers without citations can also be very good in many cases except when the question specifically called for a citation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's valid.

It declares an integer named `main`.

Comment: But where's main? And why i need to define function main in C++?

Comment: @KingsIndian well, not exactly.

Comment: @H2CO3 Since C++ doesn't allow calling main() where do you see the problem with a variable called main (apart from confusing) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think , I found one . It's not a solution but point to remember
If you use

`gcc -Wall -Werror <file.c>`

You will get warning is treated as errors:

```
main is usually a function name
```

So its best to compile with `-Wall` so that you can see all the warnings as well